# R: [Indicspecies package] multipatt function: extract values from summary.multipatt

Tags: r

I am working with the 'indicspecies' package - multipatt function and am unable to extract summary values of the package. Unfortunately I can't print all the summary and am left with impartial information for my model. The reason is the huge amount of data that needs to be printed from the summary (300.000 different species, 3 groups, 6 comparable combinations).

This is what happens with summary being saved (pre-code incl.):

```
x <- multipatt(data, ...) 

sumx <-summary(x)

sumx
```

> NULL

```
str(sumx)
```

> NULL

So, the summary does not work exactly like a generic summary. It seems that the function is based around the older indval function from the 'labdsv' package (which is mentioned in the documentation). I found an archived thread where a similar problem is discussed: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/extract-values-from-summary-of-function-indval-of-the-package-labdsv-td4637466.html

but it seems not resolved (and is not exactly about the same function, rather the base function indval).

I was wondering if anyone has experience with the indicspecies package and knows a way to either extract the info from the summary.

It is possible to extract significance and other information from the other saved data from the model, but it might be nice to just get a quick complete overview from the data.

ps. I tried

```
options(max.print=1000000)
```

but this didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use to capture the `summary` output for a `multipatt` object, but don't any more because the p-values reported are not corrected for multiple testing.  To answer the OP's question you can capture the summary output using `capture.output`

ex. 
`dat.multipatt.summary<-capture.output(summary(dat.multipatt, indvalcomp=TRUE))`

Again, I do not recommend this.  It is very important to correct the p-values for multiple testing, so the `summary` output actually isn't helpful.  To be clear `?multipatt` states:

"sign   Data table with results of the best matching pattern, the association value and the degree of statistical significance of the association (i.e. p-values from permutation test). **Note that p-values are not corrected for multiple testing**."

I just posted an answer for how to correct the p-values here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370724/indiscpecies-multipatt-and-overcoming-multi-comparrisons/401277#401277

Comment: While it is true that p-values are not corrected for multiple testing, the question that arises is whether or not the p-values should be corrected for multiple testing. Although most people would automatically say yes, it is discussed in the article that comes with the package:

Comment: They make the argument that if you are only interested in reporting that a given species is an indicator that no correction for p-values is needed. See Carecas 2010 'Improving indicator species analysis by combining groups of sites'

Comment: @GeertHensgens True, you did indicate you were interested in "extract significance", in which case correcting p-values would be appropriate.

Comment: yes that is true, however I only needed it in order to select the indicator species from the model data. Thanks anyway, I know this discussion has actually flowed into statistics a bit instead but I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with this package and since you haven't provided the data, it's difficult to reproduce. But since summary is returning NULL, are you sure your `x` is computed properly? Check the `object.size` or `class` or something else of `x` to see if it indeed has any content.
Also instead of accessing all the contents of `summary(x)` together, you can use `@` to access slots of it (similar to `$` in dataframe).

If you need further assistance, it'd be better t provide atleast a small subset or some other sample data so that the community can work with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yeah it's always better to get some data in, but it's super big data and I am not really sure if it helps a lot - as the problem is within the original labdsv package. I actually think there's not really a solution, as the old thread already (if I interpret it correctly) mentioned that the summary function is giving the wrong data-class to the summary, making extraction impossible. Either way, I thought perhaps someone has had the same problem with the same package and got a way around it.

Comment: If you think that it's a problem with the functionality of the package itself, try opening an issue in github under that. You can refer this page over there too. Could help others in future also.

Comment: Good idea, I'm not so familiar with GitHub though, but I might do it in the future. Thanks!